# Folding Drawer Layout by tibi1712

Tags: android, drawer

I'm trying to get the Folding Drawer Layout by Tibi1712 to work in Android Studio,
and can't get any result out of it.

GitHub:
https://github.com/tibi1712/FoldingNavigationDrawer-Android

This project is not written in the gradle system, so Android Studio complains about that after importing it from GitHub.

I tried to export it from Eclipse, but still I was drowning in errors.

I know this question is way too broad, 
but maybe one of you has tried it and got it to work on Android Studio?
Maybe there is a jar or aar out there, ready to use.

Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: I also facing same problem.